# React native homebrew node location not in the right place

Tags: node.js, xcode, react-native, homebrew

I'm getting the following error in Xcode when building

```
Node found at: /opt/homebrew/bin/node
/Users/adamwright/Documents/Development/AB3MobileUpgrade/AB3MobileUpgrade/ios/Pods/../../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec/../../scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.sh: line 34: /opt/homebrew/bin/node: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

It looks like my node is in the wrong path. if i do **type node** i get
**node is /usr/local/bin/node**

I tested on another machine also using homebrew and that path is **opt/homebrew/bin/node** where homebrew has installed it and the app builds!

How do I update the path to the homebrew default location so it's correct?

Comment: Does the output of `brew doctor` provide any suggestions?

Comment: @Zaq no didn't help but i fixed it

Answer (score 2):

in the ios folder is an .env file

The path in that just needed updating, it is an autogenerated file but i guess it screwed up.

```
export NODE_BINARY=/usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: Glad you resolved it.  The `Pods` folder suggests you're using CocoaPods.  It might be worth checking your `Podfile`.

Comment: I think your answer is a solution but it isn't a permanent one. please do not install NodeJs by using `homebrew`, At first install `nvm` then by using `nvm` you can change several versions and manage them. Also in the installing procedure, it tries to add its path and you won't encounter any issues at all. I upvoted your answer but I'll post another permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was installing NodeJs by using homebrew, it would lose the main path of the NodeJs folder. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77297731/6877799) is a project's local solution and maybe for another project which needs NodeJs, it would encounter the same issue.

- *Global solution*: Add the `NODE_BINARY` to your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` file as a global environment variable and concat the `/usr/local/bin/node` to your PATH system.
- *Permanent solution*: Remove the homebrew NodeJs and install [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and then by using `nvm` install any NodeJs versions you want

**With the permanent solution you won't encounter any issues ever**